# Google Sheets ArrayFormula with CountA and Filter

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, countif, flatten

I'm stuck with using counta and filter with arrayformula.
Here's my code.
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A="", , COUNTA(FILTER(FLATTEN($W$2:$Z), FLATTEN($W$2:$Z) = A3:A))))`

Desired output.
I have a list of names on column A and I want to know how many times their name appear on column W:Z without having to drag down the formula because the list on W:Z will keep on updating.

Here's the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nwXdndkoWF2p_An_iBCB2YFKzhiVzby9DPqELX1PM7s/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
=ArrayFormula(
      LAMBDA(r,u, VLOOKUP(r,{UNIQUE(u),COUNTIF(u,"="&UNIQUE(u))},2,0))
            (A3:A,FILTER(FLATTEN(W2:Z),FLATTEN(W2:Z)<>"")))
```

[image]

**Explanation**

- `FLATTEN(W2:Z),FLATTEN(W2:Z)<>"")` to get all the columns in `W2:Z` in one array, and its "stored" in a `Lambda()` call and named `u` (you can name it anything) so we can recall it in the formula without repeating the references like the option 2 below.

the lookup range `{1,2}`

- 1 `UNIQUE(u)` this is just as saying `UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(W2:Z),FLATTEN(W2:Z)<>""))`
- 2 `COUNTIF(u,"="&UNIQUE(u))` its a simple `countif`
- `VLOOKUP(r,{UNIQUE(u),COUNTIF(u,"="&UNIQUE(u))},2,1)`  `r` is lambda name of the range `A3:A`, this is a normal `vlookup`

Just like saying "not a formula!"

```
VLOOKUP(names in col A,{UNIQUE(names in col w,x,y,z),COUNTIF(names in col w,x,y,z,"="&UNIQUE(names in col w,x,y,z))},2,0)
```

---

**Option 2**
This explains the previous formula its the same without using the new `Lambda()` function.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,VLOOKUP(A3:A, {UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(W2:Z),FLATTEN(W2:Z)<>"")),COUNTIF(FILTER(FLATTEN(W2:Z),FLATTEN(W2:Z)<>""),"="&UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(W2:Z),FLATTEN(W2:Z)<>""))&"")},2,0)))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`VLOOKUP`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) - [**`UNIQUE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198) - [**`COUNTIF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) - [**`FILTER`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) - [**`FLATTEN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Thanks @Oloap the formula is corrected, make sure you take the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @Osm I learned a lot from your explanation, I really appreciate it. Thank you for your time and effort.